# Sending serial email in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Can you tell me how I can send an email where it goes from one person and onto the next person , etc etc until it is returned to the originator? I think they called it serial email in Lotus application, and know they can do it within Outlook but my memory slips !

I wish to send a document to around 5 people on a distribution list, where once opened, they edit, close and it forwards automatically to the next person in the chain, so on and so on until all 5 people have made their input into the document and is then returned to the originator. I know I used it before, and it tell the originator where the email is and who has already updated and forwarded it on.